# What does "organize the deliveries to something" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Only asking female workers to order food, while only asking male
>   workers to organize the deliveries to set could be seen as
>   discrimination.

"set" means a place to shoot a film. What does "organize the deliveries to set" mean? Does it mean "organize things to be delivered to the set"?

I can't find the source. I read it a long time ago from a material regarding discrimination at workplace.

And I also have one more question. It's similar to the above one.

> Male workers do all of the runs to set.

What does "runs to set" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question here seems fairly straightforward. "Delivery" is the presentation of some good to the people who will use it, so organizing the deliveries to set would entail such things as deciding what things should be delivered, when they should deliver them, how they will get those things to the set, etc. In this context it seems likely they are delivering the food to the actors, cameramen, directors, etc. on set.

Regarding the second question, "run" is sometimes used as a noun meaning a trip or visit, especially one with some goal attached. A "run to set" here refers to one of the trips taken to the set to make the aforementioned deliveries.